# Path for environmental variables is not working

Tags: python, windows

I have installed python 3.9.1 in a new PC through the path "C:\Python39", configured the path in the user environment variable multiple times but still I get same error " 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Below is the picture of the python path

[image]

Comment: How did you install Python? Normally you do not have to set any environment variables yourself.

Comment: When installing there are two options, the default one and customize option, so I chose customize options and marked set path category to set up by itself

Comment: Why did you do that if you don't know how? I suggest you run the installer again and choose the default option.

Answer (score -1):

This question was already covered on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path). It should answer what you are looking for.

Have a great day!

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if this does the trick, but i see ; after the path to scripts